# Why "scp" does not print all output of script specified by "command" directive of authorized_keys file (or any other startup script)

Tags: bash, ssh, openssh, scp

I need a bash script to be automatically launched when doing an `ssh` or `scp` command to a server. I do my `ssh` and `scp` this way:

```
ssh -i path/to/key me@server some_command
```

or

```
scp -i path/to/key file_to_copy me@server:/destination_folder
```

My script should detect what command was launched (`ssh` or `scp`), and then if need be parse the arguments (which in this example would be `some_command`).

For that script to be automatically launched, I added a command in the `authorized_keys`, like this:

```
command="~/script",no-pty,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-rsa ...
```

Ok, now let's say the `script` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "hello"
echo "hello1"
echo "hello2"
```

Well, doing `ssh -i path/to/key me@server some_command`, I see printed "hello", "hello1", "hello2" on my shell ("client-side"). Perfect.

**But** when doing `scp -i path/to/key file_to_copy me@server:/destination_folder`, I just see printed "hello" on my shell (client-side).

Why? How can I avoid this behavior? Note that if instead of having some `echo` I do a `cat` on some file, then in the case of the `scp` command, it would only print the first line! (and again the `ssh` command would work well and print all lines).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stdout of an SSH command is not always just your terminal.

Tools such as scp, rsync, or git actually communicate with the server-side component almost entirely through stdin/stdout – and they expect to receive messages conforming to their own protocols, not just random ASCII text.

So when the local `scp` client receives any text before it has even sent a request, it treats this as a protocol violation. It prints the first line *just to be nice*, but then exits because it's unable to talk to the remote scp handler anyway, and passing messages to the user isn't part of its functionality.

Other tools would not print any text at all. For example, rsync would just report an error:

```
$ rsync badserver:test.c /tmp
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

Same goes for Git and other tools using SSH as a transport: they expect full control over stdin & stdout, just as they would use a TCP connection. (Some clients do pass through messages that were written to *stderr* using `>&2`, but most won't; OpenSSH scp does not and PuTTY pscp does not.)

There is no fully general method to show arbitrary messages through a shellscript. But if all you need is a basic greeting, you can show *static* messages using the sshd's `Banner` option – e.g. OpenSSH server can provide different messages based on the username, group, IP address, and other conditions supported by `Match`. The SSH client will recognize the banner message as separate from the normal stdout/stderr.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very clear!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot print *anything* in sessions that use strict protocol like SCP or SFTP. You break the protocol by doing that. With `scp` (OpenSSH command-line SCP client), it might work, if you print the output to stderr. But you might break other SCP clients (like my WinSCP).

Use SSH banner instead.

For similar topics, see:

- [Welcome banner stopping scp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/355016/119732#355026)
- [SSH MOTD per user](https://serverfault.com/q/653399/168875)

---

*Though do you really want the command to print anything on the client side? Didn't you just want to debug/test your script? Did you consider writing the output to a file on the server?*

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that!